# How to pass an array as a parameter of url and receive it full

Tags: php, arrays, mercadopago

I have an array like the following:

```
$quantity = explode(",", $dataProducts["quantityArray"]);
$valuePrice = explode(",", $dataProducts["valuePriceArray"]);
$productsId = explode(",", $dataProducts["productsIdArray"]);

for($i=0;$i<count($productsId);$i++){ 

    $products = array('id' => $productsId[$i],
                      'price' => $valuePrice[$i],
                      'quantity' => $quantity[$i]);

}
```

Suppose the vector is composed of 4 products with their id, prices and quantities. (Previously I check that the array is properly armed)

> $products[0] = ['id' => 4, 'price' => 20, 'quantity' => 2]
>
> $products[1] = ['id' => 10, 'price' => 100, 'quantity' => 5]
>
> $products[2] = ['id' => 15, 'price' => 40, 'quantity' => 4]
>
> $products[3] = ['id' => 20, 'price' => 50, 'quantity' => 3]

And I'm passing it as a parameter to the url of 'success'. **But when the url is generated, only the first index of the array arrives.**

```
$products= http_build_query($products);

#Configure the url of response for user
$preference->back_urls = array(
            "success" => "{$url}/index.php?route=profile&data=".$products,
            "failure" => "{$url}/index.php?route=error",
            "pending" => "{$url}/index.php?ruta=pending"
);
```

Example of generated url, with only the first index of the array:

> https://www.webpage.com/index.php?route=profile&data=id=4&price=20&quantity=2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the vector is composed of 4 products"?

Comment: @ryantxr I put it to give as an example, that my array has 4 indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3, each with id, price and quantity

Comment: Please show fully how you are populating the array. The array you are showing does not have indexes 0, 1, 2 etc.

Comment: @ryantxr Ready. I have already modified the question with a complete example of the array

Comment: Please show the context around the first code block. Since you use `$i`, I assume there's a `for` loop around it. Add this to your post.

Comment: Given the input you provided, what is the expected output?

Comment: @Barthy ready!  I have already modified the question with a complete example of the array with for loop

Comment: @ryantxr What is expected is to receive a url with the entire array. Notice that in the end I gave an example of what always comes. That is, the first index of the array always arrives, and what is expected is that the entire array arrives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$products[0] = ['id' => 4, 'price' => 20, 'quantity' => 2];
$products[1] = ['id' => 10, 'price' => 100, 'quantity' => 5];
$products[2] = ['id' => 15, 'price' => 40, 'quantity' => 4];
$products[3] = ['id' => 20, 'price' => 50, 'quantity' => 3];
$str = http_build_query($products);
echo $str . PHP_EOL;
```

Generates this:

0%5Bid%5D=4&0%5Bprice%5D=20&0%5Bquantity%5D=2&1%5Bid%5D=10&1%5Bprice%5D=100&1%5Bquantity%5D=5&2%5Bid%5D=15&2%5Bprice%5D=40&2%5Bquantity%5D=4&3%5Bid%5D=20&3%5Bprice%5D=50&3%5Bquantity%5D=3

If you are looking for output like this:

```
id=4&price=20&quantity=2&id=10&price=100&quantity=5&id=15&price=40&quantity=4&id=20&price=50&quantity=3
```

Then do this:

```
$str2 = '';

foreach($products as $product) { 
   $tmp = http_build_query($product);
   if ( ! empty($str2) ) {
      $str2 .= '&';
   }
   $str2 .= $tmp;
}
echo $str2 . "\n";
```

You could encode the entire array as JSON base 64 encoded.

```
$data = base64_encode(json_encode($products));
echo "http://example.com/?data=" . $data . PHP_EOL;
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
$products = json_decode(base64_decode($_GET['data']), true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, if I wanted to access with "$ _GET" to my array in the path "profile" towards which it is directed, I think that this way it could not. That is, make an $ arrayURL = $ _GET [$ arrayThatComesInUrl]

Comment: If you want the input data as one element, then convert to JSON and base64 encode before sending. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to append an item to an array, use the following syntax: `$array[] = $value`

In your example:

```php
for($i=0; $i<count($productsId); $i++){ 
    $products[] = array(
        'id' => $productsId[$i],
        'price' => $valuePrice[$i],
        'quantity' => $quantity[$i]
    );
}
```